# Hierarchical Query connect by using start with clause

Tags: sql, oracle, connect-by, hierarchical-query

The data I am working with is sequenced like the below example:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk5Eb.png)

What I want to know is this:

[Want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voffk.png)

What I get from my query is this (the actual query with actual data is posted at the end of this post) :

[Get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaKPo.png)

This is the code I have now, which I feel is close to giving me what I want.

select * from (
select distinct id
     , idnew
     , CONNECT_BY_ROOT idlast
     , CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF "IsLeaf"
     , CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE iscycle 
     , level seq_order
  from mytable tbl1
  connect by NOCYCLE idnew = prior id
 start with not exists (select 1 from mytable tbl2
                         where tbl2.itemloadid = tbl.itemloadidnew)
) abc
order by abc.idlast, seq_order desc

The output I get from this code is this:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VhZS.png)

How do I make sure that the first value of my sequences are interpreted as the roots (and not the leaves as today)? As I understand it, if they are interpreted as roots I can print a column with id_first, and not the id_last I have today.

Help is much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to invert `connect by` clause:

```
select t.*, connect_by_root(id) id_first
  from mytable t 
  start with not exists (select 1 from mytable x where x.id_new = t.id)
  connect by id = prior id_new
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fd57c37c406543afe1b2115f18922bf4)</sup>**